# Formfile is empty when uploading data via antd design to aspnet core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, antd, multipartform-data

I'm performing an s3 file upload action via axios to my aspnet core web api server. I'm confused as to where I went wrong. There is data uploaded from console but web api shows no files. This is my code. Thanks for all the help.

### code upload file

```
const [fileUploads, setFileUploads] = useState([]);
//upload file
const dummyRequest = ({ file, onSuccess }) => {};

const beforeUpload = (file, fileList) => {
  return false
}

const { Dragger } = Upload;
const props = {
    accept: 'image/png, image/jpeg, image/svg, image/gif, .xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc, .docx,.ppt, .pptx,.txt,.pdf',
    name: 'file',
    multiple: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    beforeUpload:beforeUpload,
    action: dummyRequest,

    onChange({ file, fileList }) {
      if (file.status !== "uploading") {
        setFileUploads(fileList)
      }
    },

    onDrop(e) {
      console.log('Dropped files', e.dataTransfer.files);
      setFileUploads(e.dataTransfer.files)
    },
};
```

### Client request with axios:

```
const handleUploadFile = () => {
    if(fileUploads.length === 0) toastActionWarning('No files to upload');
    const formDatas = new FormData();
    fileUploads.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file);
      formDatas.append(file.name,file.originFileObj);
    });
    console.log(formDatas);
    axios
      .post('files', formDatas , { withCredentials: true })
      .then((res) => {
        //setFileDatas(res.data.data);
        toastActionSuccess('Upload successfully');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toastActionFailed('There was an error in processing');
    });
  };
```

### My server:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(List<IFormFile> files) //data is empty
    {
        var results = await _fileService.UploadSharedFile(files, ClaimsPrincipalExtensions.GetUserId<int>(User));
        return CreateActionResult(CustomResponseDto<List<FileSharedCreatedDto>>.Success(StatusCodes.Status200OK, results));
    }
```

### My console log

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are posting to "files".  What's the endpoint?  Seems like "Create" should be in there somewhere.  I.E. "axios
      .post('files'..."

Comment: @pcalkins my endpoint is api/v1/files with method post. In my case, api work. But not contain data in iformfile 

Comment: Try to add `[FromForm]` attribute. `public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)`

Comment: @YongShun files still is 0. Formfile has value but not send to controller !

Comment: Is it possible that you share the Request Payload, Headers info for the send request based on Dev Tool to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was edited my controller like this and it working !

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        var formCollection = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
        var files = formCollection.Files.ToList();
        var fileCreateds = await _fileService.UploadSharedFile(files , ClaimsPrincipalExtensions.GetUserId<int>(User));
        return CreateActionResult(CustomResponseDto<List<FileSharedCreatedDto>>.Success(StatusCodes.Status200OK, fileCreateds));
    }
```